Bigger sampling gives bigger errors in survival random forests
I have a dataset of survival data with 7 categorical variables. I am using random survival forests (randomForestSRC in R) and I have experimented with different sample sizes and number of trees.
Before I train my models I take a random sample of data. Overall, I have 1.8M data points. I have experimented with random samples of 1%, 5%, 10%, and 50%. I cannot work with the entire dataset due to the associated computational complexity (it takes several hours to run each training).
What I observed is that the bigger the sample size the bigger the error (in terms of 1 minus the C-index).
Here is what my results look like:

My question is why this happens. It seems that, consistently, the more data I use to train the random forest model, the bigger the error is.
My guess is that the more data I use, the more the algorithm  struggles to find a solution and it ends up finding a less accurate one.

Welcome to CV.
Can you describe your data in terms of input rows and columns, output columns, and categorical vs. numeric?  Can you describe the control input for number of trees?  Would you describe what options you implement in your use of "rfsrc".

your question (as I understand it):
When I add more training data things get worse, what is wrong here?
First thought: lets confirm it is set up well
Set up well would mean something like this:

Consistent test set that never touches the learner.  You take a fixed size (10k rows?) of uniform stratified random sampling for the test set before you split into the train and validation.
Repeat the tests at each level several times.  For each level of training test take (1%, 5%, ...) you re-run the tests at each number of trees a suffient number of times.  A fair start might be 30 times, or 5 times if it takes hours.  This will give you an idea of the spread in the fit at each level.

Now I need to make sure I understand your approach:
Thoughts

I'm going to assume that the dark lines on the plot are the training c-index, and the dotted are the If you had done that, and the dark lines are the means.
Here is the manual for the randomForestSRC: link

It gives this for the C-error
For survival, prediction error is measured by the C-error rate defined as 
1-C, where C is Harrell’s (Harrell et al., 1982) concordance index. The 
C-error is between 0 and 1, and measures error in ranking (classifying) 
two random individuals in terms of survival. A value of 0.5 is no better 
than random guessing. A value of 0 is perfect.


You are correct in determining that a higher C_error is bad, and a higher 1-C_error is good.

I ran several pieces of example code, but they would make this a much longer answer than most folks like.  They lead me to some questions for you:
Questions for you:

do you have input factors specified as factors, integers, or numeric?
do you have the option "save.memory=True" set?
are the test data pulled out first, as described above?
do you run multiple times at the same settings (replication)?
what is cpu utilization during compute run?  Is this a case where lapply would 10x your run-speed?
are you computing C_error or 1-C_error?  What code do you use there?
the first few trees are very informative for convergence.  What does the error look like when number of trees is 1..20, canyou include those with the others?  Those forests tend to be comparatively quite small, but show worst case variability, and can help with diagnostics.

